# Did this highly cited article accidentally flip the < and > signs in a key equation?

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

I'm a political scientist who knows stats but has little background in calculus or macroeconomics. I'm about to write in an article that another (very highly cited) article in a top tier journal made a really basic math error/typo, but before I do so I just want to get a second opinion - to make sure I'm not making a fool of myself. I've excerpted the relevant bit of the article below. At the end of the excerpt it seems like the $\lt$ and $\ge$ signs need to be flipped, right? If $p$ is “support for redistribution” and $\Delta$ is “inequality” then equation 3 ( ${\partial p \over \partial \Delta} = {\frac 12}  -{ B\over \Delta^2}$ ) implies that an increase in inequality will produce a decline in support for redistribution (i.e. the derivative will be negative) only if $B\over \Delta^2$ is GREATER than $.5.$ Here's the Article excerpt

[image]

Comment: There is no need to mention that the paper is "highly cited" in order to ask what you are asking.

Comment: Whether $\Delta^2>0.5$ would depend on how "inequality" is defined. Can you tell us how that is done?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez : ...and yet that fact is not without interest.

Comment: In what possible way is it helpful in figuring out if there is a typo or not the number of citations a paper has?

Comment: I think there is something "rare" here, it'd be useful to know what the MR model says. If $B/\Delta^2<0.5$, then any increase in inequality produces greater support for redistribution, or greater $p$.

Comment: I only mentioned the paper was highly cited to explain why I was so hesitant to accuse it of being wrong. I apologize if that was inappropriate. These models both assume that a country's income is lognormally distributed. $\Delta$ is the standard deviation of the logged (normal) distribution, which is treated as a measure of inequality since it shows how far mean income is from the median. The MR model is just $p=\Phi (\frac\Delta2)$. So the key question is: holding B constant what happens to p as $\Delta$ increases? I think the authors just got $\Delta$ and  $\frac B{\Delta^{2}}$ mixed up.

Comment: @GrahamWright, if $\Delta$ is large with respect to $B$ ($B/\Delta^2<0.5$), then both models predict essentially the same, otherwise the predictions are different. I also think that the authors switched something, you have to find out if this is a "typo", that is, at the very end they arrive to correct conclusions, or if they are indeed messing up things.

Comment: In my experience the flipping of inequality signs is one of the most usual typos in published papers (and books) ...